# Navigating between pages in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I need to navigate to specific page according to:

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(rootFrame.Name));
```

but rootFrame.Name = page name that is needed is a string not frame
Any Help!!

Comment: `rootFrame.Navigate` requires you to pass the type of the next page you want to go to. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: i don't know specifically what is the next page because it will be changed always so i try to find its name rootFrame.Name but how can i use its name in oder to switchto it any idea ?

Comment: hope you understand me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    public void NavigateToPage<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        var testvalue = (type.FullName.Substring(type.FullName.IndexOf('.')).Replace('.', '/')) + ".xaml";

        RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri(testvalue, UriKind.Relative));

    }
```